# C System can't run hello world

Tags: c, shell, process

Can anyone tell me why this simple C `system` call of a shell `hello world` command is not working:

**MWE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   char *str;

   str = strdup ( "hello" );
   printf ( "echo %s\n", str );
   system ( ( "echo %s\n", str ) );

   return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> > echo hello
> >
> > sh: 1: hello: not found

Comment: just fyi I did try "googling the problem", but the terms `C`, `System`, `not found`, `sh` do not return what I am looking for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
   system ( ( "echo %s\n", str ) );
```

The [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) simply returns the second value, `str`, which is `"hello"`. Therefore your program will not try to run `echo hello` but just `hello`.

You'll want to use `sprintf` to write the entire command into a buffer, then execute that.

Answer (score 3):

The line:

```
system ( ( "echo %s\n", str ) );
```

Tries to run the system command `"hello"`, which, naturally, is not a valid command.

This is because you are using the [comma-operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), which only takes on the value of the right-most parameter.  In this case, the right-most is `str`, which is a pointer to string `"hello"`.

*(The left-param, `"echo %s\n"`, is ignored in the call to `system`)*

---

Assuming that you intend to call:

```
system("echo hello");
```

You need to do something like:

```
char *str;
char outstring[100] = {0};

str = strdup ( "hello" );
sprintf (outstring, "echo %s\n", str);
system (outstring);
```

The `sprintf` line will build the string `"echo hello\n"`, and put it in `outstring`.
The `system` call will then execute that command.

*(note that I set the size of `outstring` to a fixed size of **100**.  This is unsafe, if your `sprintf` should generate more output than that, but this was the simplest thing to do for demonstration purposes)*

Comment: yes, I am sorry but the `printf` command was just to show that I am outputting `echo hello` and not `derp derp` ;-)

Comment: I don't understand, then how do I tell it to execute `hello world`?

Comment: out of curiosity, what is the purpose of `= {0}`

Comment: It initializes the whole array to zero.  Not strictly necessary, as the `sprintf` function will end the string with 0 too.  But safety is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- `system()` (or string literals with a `%`) doesn't do % substitution like `printf`
- The double parentheses make the comma a comma operator yielding its right argument (`str`), not two arguments. C isn't Python :-)